# PhoneGap and Cordova alternative

Tags: cordova

What alternatives are there for PhoneGap and Cordova?
I'm need to complete some research for native apps with HTML/CSS/js, but I didn't find anything except for them.

Answer (score 6):

I just compile a list over the weekend.

- [Hybrid Frameworks](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/hybrid-frameworks.md)

Many of these frameworks cross-over directly into Cordova and Phonegap. The largest differentiator is they have UIs – Cordova and Phonegap do not. You build your own, or borrow the UI frameworks from "Web Apps"

The page linked to has the following CLI and Cloud-based providers. The page also has links to the supporting websites. There are more, but most use Cordova to some extent. Mostly because the have the most momentum. The other players are usually working of the same idea, *a webview library with supporting plugins*.

```
Phonegap
Ionic
Monaca
Onsen UI
Taco
Telerik
Cocoon
Framework7
Aerogear Platforms - limited intended for "enterprise mobile"
Mobile Angular UI
Sencha Touch
Kendo UI
```

Answer (score 1):

[React Native](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/) could be an alternative, it's still pretty new (especially for Android) but has some good thinkers behind it at Facebook and would be easy to learn if you know ReactJS.

There's also solutions such as [Titanium Appcelerator](http://www.appcelerator.com/product/#AppsSect).

I have dabbled in both and found them both fairly approachable - I have been able to get quick proof of concepts done quickly.  I don't have any direct experience taking an app written with either to the App Store though.

Answer (score 0):

Appcelerator Titanium is a very good alternative. It also has a MVC framework alloy and it uses JavaScript. It packages a native app from the JavaScript code. It is available for android, iOS and windows phone. It's a very good platform to build native apps quickly. You can either code in JavaScript or use alloy MVC which uses XML for views and JavaScript for controller and models.

Answer (score 0):

Ionic Capaciter - https://capacitor.ionicframework.com/

React Native - https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/webview.html

Answer (score -1):

Try [Intel's App XDK](https://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-xdk). Seems to be good.

As told in this [post](https://www.linkedin.com/grp/post/2868882-239384714), there's others like [Xamarin](http://xamarin.com/), if you use C#.

Comment: XDK builds with Cordova, so this doesn't answer the question.